# New login email repeatedly

Tags: c#, instasharp

I'm using instasharper library https://github.com/a-legotin/InstaSharper in one project and I have mails like
*New login to Instagram from Instagram app on Asus razor*
every time when I'm trying to run my app and login to Instagram servers.
I found that there is automatically assigned random device. And I changed my code just for using the same device always

```
    var d = AndroidDeviceGenerator.GetByName(sett.deviceType);
    d.PhoneGuid = Guid.Parse(sett.phoneGuid);
    d.GoogleAdId = Guid.Parse(sett.googleGUID);
    d.RankToken = Guid.Parse(sett.rankToken);
    d.AdId = Guid.Parse(sett.Adid);
    d.AndroidVer = AndroidVersion.GetAndroidVersion("19");
    d.DeviceGuid = Guid.Parse(sett.deviceGuid);
    api.SetDevice(d);
```

But e-mails still received. I'm afraid that in the end my accounts will be blocked.

Comment: Guess:  you need to be passing a persistent cookie that Instagram tried to set in your browser after your login.  It's like when sites forget you after a Chrome update clears your cookies, or once every n days when a site cookie expires.

Comment: It is looks like android application, I'm not sure that cookies used inside. But thanks I have to check in log files. And it is not clear how to use these cookies inside library.